# hrulefill vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, rules

I want to reduce the vertical spacing that comes before and after \hrulefill. [image]
I have already tried different options with \hrule, which works fine except for the fact that the line doesn't end where the right margin starts (whereas \hrulefill does)
[image]

Here is the minimum example code :

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{resume} 
\section{EDUCATION}

{\bf University}, Town, Country \\
Degree Title \hfill {\bf{Date}} 
\begin{itemize}\itemsep -2pt
\item item 1
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\section{WORK EXPERIENCE}

{\bf Job} Town, Country \hfill {\bf{Date}} 
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just insert negative `\vspace`s as needed, like in the example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}

\section{EDUCATION}

{\bfseries University}, Town, Country \\
Degree Title \hfill {\bfseries Date}
\begin{itemize}
  \itemsep -2pt
  \item item 1
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\hrulefill

\vspace{-.7\baselineskip}

\section{WORK EXPERIENCE}

{\bfseries Job} Town, Country \hfill {\bfseries Date}
\begin{itemize}
  \item item 1
\end{itemize}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the `\hrulefill` by:

```
\rule[\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
```

Of course, you can change `\baselineskip` and `-\baselineskip` for the spaces that you want. The advantage over set the negatives or positives spaces before and after a `\hrulefill` is that you control the  default `0.4pt` thickness and also width (that being `\linewidth` will fill the line).