# When should I use `\par` and when should I use `\hrule height 0pt`?

Tags: spacing, boxes, rules, vertical

I commonly run into issues with controlling the exact amount of space between two environments.

Recently, for example, I was trying to understand how to insert a horizontal rule between two boxes without adding extraneous space.  The following example does what I want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
BEFORE 1\\BEFORE 2
\hrule
AFTER 1\\AFTER 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wanted to replicate this with `\hrulefill` instead, to customize the width of the rule and add additional elements on the rule's line, but this does not work (the `\offinterlineskip` setting applies to too much):

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
BEFORE 1\\BEFORE 2\par
\hrulefill\par
AFTER 1\\AFTER 2\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the following works, without having to change `\parskip`, `\lineskip`, or any other parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
BEFORE 1\\BEFORE 2\hrule height 0pt
\hrulefill\hrule height 0pt
AFTER 1\\AFTER 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

What role does `\hrule height 0pt` play here, exactly?  How does it compare to `\par`, and what would be the equivalent sequence of commands using `\par` to generate the example below? (In other words, how would one emulate `\hrule` using `\hrulefill` and `\par`?)

Comment: I have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454389/hrulefill-vertical-spacing , but the answer to this question just suggest adding add-hoc negative vertical spaces around the `\hrulefill`, and I'd like to understand there's anything wrong with the (seemingly) more robust `\hrule height=0pt`

Comment: Normally TeX tries to put baselines `\baselineskip` apart, but if the calculated `\vskip` is less than `\lineskiplimit` it uses `\lineskip` instead.  `\hrule` ignores all that.